# DESCRIBE TABLE see which columns are NOT NULL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

In Apache Spark SQL (Azure Databricks), I created a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(
    a BIGINT,
    b BIGINT NOT NULL
)
```

I have verified that I have one nullable column and one non-nullable column, as I get an error if I try to insert `NULL` in column `b` but I can insert null in column `a`.

However, the following statement

```sql
DESCRIBE TABLE t
```

does not tell me which columns are nullable and which are not null. Neither does `DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED`. How can I get the full description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark SQL [auxiliary commands](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html#auxiliary-statements) like `DESCRIBE TABLE` and `SHOW COLUMNS` do not display column NULL constraints as per the docs.

There is this command:

```sql
SHOW TABLE EXTENDED like 't'
```

which returns the schema in the `information` column along with others information but not much readable.

```scala
//Table Properties: [transient_lastDdlTime=1643396075]
//.....
//Partition Provider: Catalog
//Schema: root
// |-- a: long (nullable = true)
// |-- b: long (nullable = false)
```

---

But if you can use [`spark.catalog`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html) with scala/python api then this is simple:

```scala
spark.catalog.listColumns("t").show()
//+----+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+
//|name|description|dataType|nullable|isPartition|isBucket|
//+----+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+
//|   a|       null|  bigint|    true|      false|   false|
//|   b|       null|  bigint|   false|      false|   false|
//+----+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = "database_name"
AND
TABLE_NAME ="t"
```

Column name your looking for is called "IS_NULLABLE"

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting "Table or view not found: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" - I think this only works in Microsoft SQL Server. Is there an equivalent for Apache Spark? (I didn't downvote, by the way. It was someone else)

Comment: This is implemented in Hive metastore v.3.+ https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HIVE-1010 Maybe its time to upgrade?